# How to host different nginx docker-compose instances on the same server?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I want to create/host multiple applications on 1 server. This will happen through docker-compose. This docker-compose has 3 instances: web, db and nginx.

So each application will start from a `docker-compose up` command.

The question I still have is: do I need the nxinx inside the docker-compose config, or should I create 1 nginx config?

Why this question? I want to run a single command to run 1 application, instead of running a command and alter the nginx config over and over again.

Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to start only those 3 services, or more projects?

Comment: For each project, I want to start those 3 services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is expose the service (web) for each project in the host on a different port and have a central nginx docker container - or an nginx installation that would define the reverse proxying for each application.

Comment: Having a central nginx docker will result in me having to change this config for each application I run?

Comment: You need a way to update its configuration on each deployment for it to route properly. Otherwise you need a container orchestration platform like kubernetes.

Comment: That's what I thought. So it's not possible that each application that I run has it's own nginx config? This config will always be the same, except for the port.

Comment: Well, you can do that but you can only have one nginx listening on each port (eg 80/443), thats the problem